# Control the -isystem option in clang from CmakeList.txt

Tags: c++, cmake, thrift

When trying to compile fbthrift on my mac (version info: ProductName:            macOS ProductVersion:         13.4.1 BuildVersion:           22F82) using Cmake and clang++, I got a bunch of compilation errors as below:

```
[build] /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/math.h:170:5: note: expanded from macro 'signbit'
[build]     ( sizeof(x) == sizeof(float)  ? __inline_signbitf((float)(x))
```

and after investigation, it turns out to be the mix of the include from the brew and mac os developer tools that cause some of the conflicts.

Checking the clang command generated from the CmakeLists.txt, I found out the command was: `[build] /usr/bin/clang++ -DBOOST_ATOMIC_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_ATOMIC_NO_LIB -DBOOST_CONTEXT_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_CONTEXT_NO_LIB -DBOOST_FILESYSTEM_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_FILESYSTEM_NO_LIB -DBOOST_PROGRAM_OPTIONS_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_PROGRAM_OPTIONS_NO_LIB -DBOOST_REGEX_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_REGEX_NO_LIB -DBOOST_SYSTEM_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_SYSTEM_NO_LIB -DBOOST_THREAD_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_THREAD_NO_LIB -DFMT_SHARED -DGFLAGS_IS_A_DLL=0 -DTHRIFT_HAVE_LIBSNAPPY=0 -I/Users/kaiqu/Developer/fbthrift/. -I/Users/kaiqu/Developer/fbthrift/build -I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/include -isystem /opt/homebrew/include -isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include -g -std=c++20 -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk -MD -MT thrift/annotation/CMakeFiles/thriftannotation.dir/gen-cpp2/cpp_data.cpp.o -MF thrift/annotation/CMakeFiles/thriftannotation.dir/gen-cpp2/cpp_data.cpp.o.d -o thrift/annotation/CMakeFiles/thriftannotation.dir/gen-cpp2/cpp_data.cpp.o -c /Users/kaiqu/Developer/fbthrift/build/thrift/annotation/gen-cpp2/cpp_data.cpp`

As can be seen from the above, the -isystem includes both the headers in brew and ones in mac os developer tools. After removing those -isystem arguments and run the build command manually it was build successfully.

Is there anyway to turn off the isystem arguments manually from CmakeLists.txt?

Comment: I've skipped to much details what is actual problem. What is your target? To what your target links to? Which of dependencies introduces problematic include directory? Is this some order issue or is this macro impacts your code? Some time ago I had similar issue with fmt library and solved this with macro.

Comment: is that really a warning? I just says "note:"... or did you chop off too much of the diagnostic message? Can you actually give a full error message and a [mre]?